# Arbitrary JSON keys with Aeson - Haskell

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have a bunch of nested JSON objects with arbitrary keys.

```
{
    "A": {
        "B": {
            "C": "hello"

        }
    }

}
```

Where `A`, `B`, `C` are unknown ahead of time.  Each of those three could also
have siblings.

I'm wondering if there is a way to parse this into a custom type with Aeson in
some elegant way.  What I have been doing is loading it into an Aeson `Object`.

How would you go about implementing the `FromJSON` for this kind of JSON
object?

Thanks!

**Edit**:

```
{
    "USA": {
        "California": {
            "San Francisco": "Some text"
        }
    },
    "Canada": {
        ...
    }
}
```

This should compile to `CountryDatabase` where...

```
type City            = Map String String
type Country         = Map String City
type CountryDatabase = Map String Country
```

Comment: It's not really clear *how* would you like to parse this JSON. Does it always only have 3 nested keys and then the string?

Comment: Can you give an example of the custom type you'd like to parse into? I think that would clarify the question.

Comment: Question updated with a more concrete example of the data structures.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can reuse `FromJSON` instance of `Map String v`. Something like the next:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Functor
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
import System.Environment

newtype City = City (Map String String)
  deriving Show

instance FromJSON City where
  parseJSON val = City <$> parseJSON val

newtype Country = Country (Map String City)
  deriving Show

instance FromJSON Country where
  parseJSON val = Country <$> parseJSON val

newtype DB = DB (Map String Country)
  deriving Show

instance FromJSON DB where
  parseJSON val = DB <$> parseJSON val

main :: IO ()
main = do
  file <- head <$> getArgs
  str <- LBS.readFile file
  print (decode str :: Maybe DB)
```

The output:

```
shum@shum-lt:/tmp/shum$ cat in.js 
{
    "A": {
        "A1": {
            "A11": "1111",
            "A22": "2222"
        }
    },
    "B": {
    }
}
shum@shum-lt:/tmp/shum$ runhaskell test.hs in.js 
Just (DB (fromList [("A",Country (fromList [("A1",City (fromList [("A11","1111"),("A22","2222")]))])),("B",Country (fromList []))]))
shum@shum-lt:/tmp/shum$
```

PS: You can do it without `newtype`s, I used them only for clarity.

Comment: This answer is very helpful! Could this be modified to ignore non-string values? (Replacing `"1111"` with `1111`, for example, causes the parse to fail.)

Comment: How would a ToJSON instance look like for this?