# How to implement toJSON for an assoc-list producing an object with key-values pairs generically (using Aeson)?

Tags: json, haskell, associative-array, generic-programming, aeson

I have data which is a map. To make the question more concrete, let's think that it's represented as an assoc-list `type D val = [(Key,val)]` (or as `type D val = Map Key val`).

- `Key` is an "enum" type -- a sum of nullary constructors, e.g.:

  data Key = C1 | C2 | C3
- There must be `instance ToJSON` for `val`.

I'd like to implement

```
instance ToJSON val => ToJSON (D val)
```

which would be like `instance Map String val` (producing an object with the corresponding key-value pairs) ([an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17282146/94687), [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358658/94687) for `HashMap`s), only more generic.

More generic means that I'm not restricted to `String` or `Text` as the key (such instances for `Map` are found in the aeson package).

I want to learn how to use the generic mechanisms in aeson to do this concisely.

aeson already can convert "enums" to JSON strings, and also `(C val1 val2 ...)` to objects with a single key (the constructor name, like this I assume: `{ "C":[val1,val2,...] }`) with `genericToJSON defaultOptions{ sumEncoding = ObjectWithSingleField }`. And another conversion which uses the constructor names is with the default options for data types with non-nullary constructors: then the constructor name becomes the value of a `"tag"` key. I could use similar code.

I think that even such an instance (for maps whose keys are from enums) would be useful addition to the library. But AFAIU neither [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) nor [generic-aeson](https://github.com/silkapp/generic-aeson) (which has adds some nicer conversion options) has such a conversion predefined.

Comment: "I think that even such an instance (for maps whose keys are from enums) would be useful addition to the library" -> I've never needed that instance, your use case seems fairly specific, I'm not sure it would be particularly useful to have defined in the `aeson` package.  The real problem I see here is converting `Map Key val` to `Map Text val`, then outputting that.  Why not just write a function that converts your keys to a type that already instances `ToJSON` instead of worrying about generic programming?

Comment: @bheklilr I like that the constructor names from Haskell are re-used as key names. I actually plan to vary this enum when working on my project, so I don't want to maintain the functions for Text <-> Key conversions (the other direction might be needed for FromJSON; well, not necessarily, because aeson can live with single `Options` for both directions of conversion, having a single `fieldLabelModifier` for both direections, and I see how this can be done for an enum.)

Comment: @bheklilr I felt that this is somehow in spirit of Aeson to represent many native Haskell data types as JSON without relying on user-supplied conversions to text. I find this joyful.

Comment: @bheklilr Re "Why not just write a function that converts your keys to a type that already instances ToJSON instead of worrying about generic programming?" I assume the keys do instance `ToJSON`, that's not a problem for me. But that wouldn't automatically (or with some options) give me the desired JSON representation. Yes, with a "hack" I can really write a short implementation of what I want (my answer below) relying on the `instance ToJSON Key`, but that's ugly. The generic bit of code that works in such default `instance ToJSON Key` could be directly used here, instead of the non-total λ.

Comment: Using a record instead of a map (where the fields are instead of my enum type constructors) is not something convenient for me because it doesn't allow to do computations on the `Key` data.

Comment: See also [A general serializer for Data.Map](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/79).

Answer (score 1):

A quick and short, but ugly solution is:

```
instance (ToJSON a) => ToJSON (D a)
    where toJSON kvs = object [ t .= v | (k,v) <- kvs, let (String t) = toJSON k ]
```

Advantages:

- it re-uses the generic mechanisms of aeson to get the key representation (as text);
- it would re-use the same conversion rules for the names of the fields here as defined in the `instance ToJSON Key`, so we don't need to write them twice, or to care about consistency.

Disadvantages:

- converting first to `Object` just to extract a `String` is simply ugly;
- it introduces a dangerous non-total conversion (which even may fail if `toJSON` for `Key` is implemented in a non-default way;
- there is no compile-time check that `Key` is an enum relying on types. (Actually, I'm not very keen on understanding the generics type machinery yet, so I see that such checks and choices can be done because aeson is implemented this way, but I wouldn't be able to write this myself yet.)